# Regex to match a string that contains two words

Tags: regex, perl

I have a strings like this

1. `Start the function "function name" (any words here ie .*) (0x10)` or
2. `'Lets start function "function name" (any words here ie .*) (0x0B)` or  etc etc..
3. `function "function name" will start (any words here ie .*) (0x0C).`

Actually, I need a regular expression that matches `Start` and `function` words in specific order in a string not necessary that `Start` word should be at the beginning of the line as per `string2`
ie `Start` should be the first occurrence and `function` word should be second irrespective of their placements in a string.

The third string above will not match because `Start` word comes after the word `function`. If the Reg ex matches then I need to capture `"function name"` ie `string inside double quotes`   and `(0x10)ie hex values` inside `()`.

I have tried the following regexp which didn't help

`^(?=.*\bStart\b)(?=.*\bfunction\b)"(.*?)".*\((\b0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b)\).*$`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @s = (
    'Start the function "function name" with (0x10)',
    'Lets start function "function name" with (0x0B)',
    'function "function name" will start with (0x0C)',
    'Start function "API"tovalue:"Enabled"(0x01)',
);

for my $s (@s) {

    my ($f, $h) = ($s =~ m{
            [Ss]tart
            [ ]
            .*?
            function
            [ ]
            "( [^"]+ )"
            [^(]+
            [(]
            ( 0x[[:xdigit:]]+ )
            [)]
        }x
    ) or next;

    print "Function name: '$f'. Hex value: '$h'\n";
}
```

Comment: See. When you know the language it turns out much better! Nice one :)

Comment: Hi Sinan.. thanks for the reply... but say for example "Start function "API"tovalue:"Enabled"(0x01)" this regex dosn't match cos of word 'with' you used in the regex... it can be anything.. I used .* instead of 'with'but no success... how can i make it general to select API and 0x01

Comment: Update the question with the correct specification. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have updated.. it can be any sentence or words between the quotes and parentheses.. Hope you understood now.

Comment: Please help me with this regard

Comment: Thanks a lot Sinan.. great work... Sorry i couldnt up vote  cos of lack of reputations.. but great answer.. once again thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I think it is clearer to separate the validation of the string and the field extraction.

This program shows my point

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = (
  'Start the function "function_one" with (0x10)',
  'Lets start function "function_two" with (0x0B)',
  'function "function_three" will start with (0x0C)',
);

for (@data) {
  next unless /\bstart\b.*\bfunction\b/i;
  printf "%s %s\n", $1, $2 if /"(.*?)".*\(0x([0-9a-f]+)\)/i;
}
```

**output**

```
function_one 10
function_two 0B
```

Comment: I like the fact you separate out the two which makes what you're doing easier to understand. Maintenance is 90% of programming.

Comment: hi..Can this can be done is single regex? it works fine in this scenario as well "Lets start "function_two" function with "enable" (0x0B)"... but single line regex will be great one

Comment: Why do you want a single regex?

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify. You don't need the lookaheads.

```
.*\bStart\b.*\bfunction\b.*"(.*?)".*\((0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)\).*
```

And if you use a find function instead of a match, you can probably skip the .* in the start and end..

That said, I'm not familiar with Perl so I'm not sure what I posted works or how to use find in Perl. Maybe someone else can help with if you need. But, at least, you get the general idea.

Edit: Forgot a `.*` before the `"`

Comment: You don't need the `.*` at the beginning and end, they might make things really, horribly slow (although I did not measure in this case). Also, [`\b` can give surprising results](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/04/using-b-in-regex-patterns-can-lead-to.html).